# Invalidate touch event

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an activity containing several fragments which the user can switch between. But I've found that if the user holds down a button, changes fragments, and only then releases the button, the button press registers upon release (even though the button is on a fragment that's not currently being shown), which can cause some strange effects. I would like to be able to make some call upon switching fragments that invalidates any currently ongoing touch events, so holding down a button while switching fragments will have no effect.

Does there exist a way to invalidate all currenly ongoing touch events?

Comment: I don't know if you can invalidate a touch event, but you could override `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)`, and when you detect a `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`, check if you've changed fragment or not, then return yes or no (yes means you've consumed the event, so don't propagate it).

Comment: @user2713030 I was expecting that suggestion to lead to terrible, convoluted, and surely buggy code to get the sort of behavior I want, but when I tried it, it actually worked out quite well. Thanks!